# Beer gushing at day 5 of bottling: Bottle bombs?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, cooling, maturation

I bottle my beer 5 days ago, and today I just opened for a test purpose, and it gushed. It is an Ale, and instructions say I should keep it in a warm place 2 weeks before putting to cool place.

Should I put my bottles to fridge to prevent bottle bombs?

Comment: What was your volumes, FG, expected TG, priming sugar amount and type? Anything 10 sg points over TG after adding priming sugar are at risk of making bottle bombs.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist 17.5 liters, FG was exactly what was Written (1013),priming sugar just got out of the kit.

Comment: sounds like maybe the priming sugar wasn't mixed well and some bottles got more than others.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist should i dump it, fridge it or wait the bomb?

Comment: typically the last few bottles would be effected with more sugar, the beginning may have less than needed. I would burb and reseal the later bottles and hope the early ones carb.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist I put the early ones in fridge, and later ones are still in the bottles. Should i tane put of early ones from fridge?

Comment: refrigeration may not stop them from fermenting. Many ale yeasts don't go dormant in even 35° If they can still feed.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist if I put fridge all of them now, what is the down side? They will not mature?

Comment: worse case scenario. They blow up in the fridge.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist how about taste ? Does it matter if I keep them 2 weeks at 70F vs 40F?

Comment: well if you do halt the conditioning, they may be sweet from the priming sugar. I would keep them at 70f, but burb the bottles to release excess pressure now.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist why is burping bottles? Take cap off and recap?

Comment: usually you can gently pry them open just to release gas, then recrimp with your capper. If you, bend the cap just remove it and recap it.

Comment: *burp not burb. Just noticed the autocorrect fails.

Answer (score 2):

Never had bottle bombs, but what I would do is the following: refrigerate all bottles, and carefully open and re-cap each one.

You release the extra pressure, when opening the bottle and will stop the yeast from producing more CO2 with cooling the beer.